# How to appened Data in JQGrid table Cell?

Tags: jqgrid

I have created JQGrid.

I have put the Data in cell and one html Link in cells.

OnClick of that link I need to open JQGrid Specific popUp.Popup have one combobox .I'll select one option and click submit button and that data needs to be appear in clicked cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The construction which you suggest seems me too complex. Probably you can consider to use more simple user interface?

Nevertheless you can just use [setCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to set new contain of the cell of the grid.